# Perform MultiTouch action with Appium for C# on Android emulator

Tags: c#, android-emulator, appium, appium-android

I‘m trying to get a MultiTouch action (zoom in) to work with C# Appium and android emulator.

In emulator I tried already to hold the ctrl-key and move the mouse, but no success. It‘s even not showing the indicator (green point in emulator screen centre) for active multi touch action. Before that, I tried the usual way with

```bash
int x = 1000 / 2;
int y = 2000 / 2;
var firstAction = new TouchAction(driver).Press(x - 100, y - 100).MoveTo(x - 500, y - 500).Release();
var secondAction = new TouchAction(driver).Press(x + 100, y + 100).MoveTo(x + 500, y + 500).Release();
var multiTouch = new MultiAction(driver);
multiTouch.Add(firstAction).Add(secondAction).Perform();
```

I splitted the code also in seperate parts and ran it, but no success. I activated the visualization of taps in developer options and the emulator screen flashes at execution of the function, so there is something happen. But I can’t figure out, how to Zoom in or Zoom out with the MultiTouch action. I read already a lot of threads here and elsewhere about it, but I found no different options to solve this issue. Maybe someone has an idea? Please help. :)

Thank you and best regards,

Dave